# macOS custom malloc/free using DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES not loaded early enough

Tags: c, macos, debugging, memory, malloc

I'm trying to write my own malloc/free wrappers to catch buffer overruns. The reason: Guard Malloc is not aggressive enough because it cannot catch overruns unless they are near page boundaries. I don't mind detecting the overrun later (when the memory is freed), but I *do* mind not detecting it.

I have used interposing and `DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES` to inject my implementations of malloc and free.  The problem is that it looks like there are calls to malloc that are made before my dynamic library gets loaded. When those objects are freed, my `free()` thinks they're corrupt because the prologue and epilogue I want to add are not present.

My code looks like this:

```
#define DYLD_INTERPOSE(_replacment,_replacee) \
__attribute__((used)) static struct{ const void* replacment; const void* replacee; } _interpose_##_replacee \
__attribute__ ((section ("__DATA,__interpose"))) = { (const void*)(unsigned long)&_replacment, (const void*)(unsigned long)&_replacee };

static const char *premagic = "abcdefgh";
static const char *postmagic = "zyxwvuts";
static const size_t prologueLength = 16;
static const size_t sizeOffset = 8;
static const size_t preMagicOffset = 0;
static const size_t epilogueLength = 8;
static const size_t totalOverhead = prologueLength + epilogueLength;

static void WriteMetadata(void *p, size_t size) {
    memmove(p + preMagicOffset, premagic, 8);
    memmove(p + sizeOffset, &size, sizeof(size));
    memmove(p + prologueLength + size, postmagic, 8);
}

static void CheckMemory(void *ptr) {
    void *realP = ptr - prologueLength;

    // Get size
    size_t size;
    memmove(&size, realP + sizeOffset, sizeof(size_t));

    // Check premagic
    if (memcmp(realP + preMagicOffset, premagic, 8)) {
        while (1);
    }

    // Check postmagic
    void *post = ptr + size;
    if (memcmp(post, postmagic, 8)) {
        while (1);
    }
}

void *ITMalloc(size_t size) {
    void *p = malloc(size + totalOverhead);
    if (p == 0) {
        return p;
    }
    WriteMetadata(p, size);
    return p + prologueLength;
}
DYLD_INTERPOSE(ITMalloc, malloc);

void ITFree(void *ptr) {
    CheckMemory(ptr);

    void *realP = ptr - prologueLength;
    free(realP);
}
DYLD_INTERPOSE(ITFree, free);

... and more for calloc, realloc, etc. ...
```

Here's how I run it:

```
DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=libitmalloc.dylib ./helloworld
```

Trouble is, my `ITFree` function gets called with a `ptr` that was never allocated by `ITMalloc`. Using `MallocStackLogging` I can see that it was allocated by part of the dynamic loader during boostrapping. Here's the stack trace of the first such allocation:

```
 0x10261d036 (dyld) _dyld_start 
 0x10261d503 (dyld) dyldbootstrap::start(macho_header const*, int, char const**, long, macho_header const*, unsigned long*) 
 0x102623709 (dyld) dyld::_main(macho_header const*, unsigned long, int, char const**, char const**, char const**, unsigned long*) 
 0x10261e71f (dyld) dyld::initializeMainExecutable() 
 0x10262ee05 (dyld) ImageLoader::runInitializers(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&) 
 0x10262ed73 (dyld) ImageLoader::processInitializers(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) 
 0x10262fb80 (dyld) ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, char const*, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) 
 0x10262fb80 (dyld) ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, char const*, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) 
 0x10262fb80 (dyld) ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, char const*, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&)
 0x10262fb80 (dyld) ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, char const*, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) 
 0x10262fb80 (dyld) ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, char const*, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) 
 0x10262fbea (dyld) ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, char const*, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) 
 0x102634798 (dyld) ImageLoaderMachO::doInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) 
 0x102634592 (dyld) ImageLoaderMachO::doModInitFunctions(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) 
 0x7fff76ad49c5 (libSystem.B.dylib) libSystem_initializer 
 0x7fff79cccad2 (libdispatch.dylib) libdispatch_init 
 0x7fff79cc0e36 (libdispatch.dylib) _os_object_init 
 0x7fff784ce234 (libobjc.A.dylib) _objc_init 
 0x7fff79cf9a27 (libdyld.dylib) _dyld_objc_notify_register 
 0x10262162e (dyld) dyld::registerObjCNotifiers(void (*)(unsigned int, char const* const*, mach_header const* const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*)) 
 0x10262147b (dyld) dyld::notifyBatchPartial(dyld_image_states, bool, char const* (*)(dyld_image_states, unsigned int, dyld_image_info const*), bool, bool) 
 0x7fff784e1560 (libobjc.A.dylib) map_images 
 0x7fff784cea50 (libobjc.A.dylib) map_images_nolock 
 0x7fff784cfa92 (libobjc.A.dylib) _read_images 
 0x7fff784d0847 (libobjc.A.dylib) NXCreateMapTable 
 0x7fff784d089d (libobjc.A.dylib) NXCreateMapTableFromZone 
 0x7fff784d09c0 (libobjc.A.dylib) NXCreateHashTable 
 0x7fff784d0aff (libobjc.A.dylib) NXCreateHashTableFromZone 
 0x7fff784d0de4 (libobjc.A.dylib) NXHashInsert 
 0x7fff79ebb1b0 (libsystem_malloc.dylib) malloc_zone_calloc
```

Am I to conclude that the only solution is to maintain a side table of "known pointers" which I know have my prologue/epilogue, and to not rely on hooking `malloc` before any other users of it? Or is there a way to get my code loaded earlier that I haven't found?

Comment: It makes sense that dyld would need to run the initializers libSystem before those of the library to be inserted by DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES - since it can't tell what those initializers might do in general.  And as the backtrace shows, initializing libSystem does require allocations.  So you are probably stuck with the fact that there will be allocations your library doesn't get to see.